# MySQL optimize query with Date range

Tags: mysql, select, optimization

I have the following table structure.

```
id (INT) index
date (TIMESTAMP) index
companyId (INT) index
```

**This is the problem I am facing**

**companyId 111:** hasta a total of *100000* rows in a 1 year time period.

**companyId 222:** has a total of *8000*  rows in a 1 year time period.

If **companyId 111** has *100* rows between `'2020-09-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-09-06 23:59:59'` and **companyId 222** has *2000* rows in the same date range, **companyId 111** is much slower than **222** even if it has less rows in the selected date range.

Shouldn't MySQL ignore all the rows outside the date range so the query becomes faster?

This is a query example I am using:

```
SELECT columns FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN '2020-09-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-09-06 23:59:59' AND companyId = 111;
```

Thank you

Comment: Please post TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE table; so we can see if you have applied any of the suggestions to this point in time. Someone will help you get high performance.

Comment: Would you have time to post current TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE table; so we can see what you ended up with for a table with indexes?

Comment: It would be ok to respond - No.  We would understand.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a *composite* index here:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON yourTable (companyId, date);
```

The problem with your premise is that, while you have an index on each column, you don't have any indices completely covering the `WHERE` clause of your example query.  As a result, MySQL might even choose to not use any of your indices.  You can also try reversing the order of the index above to compare performance:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON yourTable (date, companyId);
```

Comment: Should I create this new Index and leave the others intact or should I edit/remove them?

Comment: @CrashOverride - Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; we can't guess at what other indexes you have.  In general, toss any index that is the _left_ part of another index.

Comment: Put `companyID` _first_ because it is tested with"=".  Then all the necessary 'rows' of the index are consecutive.

Comment: @RickJames I also would have suggested the first version under the assumption that `companyId` would have higher cardinality.

Comment: Cardinality is _not_ relevant.  The structure of the index _is_.